# How can I use route namespace?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am creating routes in codeigniter-4 and I want to know if I can use namespace for some routes like with laravel given below:

**Laravel namespace Code**

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->group(function () {
    // Controllers Within The "App\Http\Controllers\Admin" Namespace
});
```

Can I implement something similar in codeigniter-4 ?

**My Codeigniter code**

```
$routes->get('/admin', 'AdminController::index', ['filter' => 'auth']);
$routes->get('/admin/channels', 'ChannelController::index', ['filter' => 'auth']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

```
$routes->group('api', ['namespace' => 'add your namespace here'], function($routes)
{
   $routes->get('/admin', 'AdminController::index', ['filter' => 
      'auth']);
}
```

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html#assigning-namespace

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
$routes->group('admin', ['filter' => 'auth', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin'], function($routes)
{
     $routes->get('/', 'AdminController::index');
     $routes->get('channels', 'ChannelController::index');
}
```